# Android API 23 - Screen On/Off while keeping network active?

Tags: android

This is my first attempt at an Android App. I've searched and haven't found (or understood) the right answer so far.

I'm working with an non-interactive display [no touch, no proximity sensor, no permanent KB or mouse, etc.] that is running Android 6.0.1. Have a simple TCP/IP connection to update content on the display, etc.

Generally works well but would like to be able to turn off the display/backlight when not in use but keep the TCP connection alive so I can turn it back on. (If I just blank the content of my full-screen activity the backlight leaves a noticeable glow that won't really work for the planned use)

When I set

`getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

It works beautifully at keeping the display long. However, when I remove that flag using

`getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

not only does the display power off within 15 seconds [as configured from the Android system settings] it also seems it drops the WiFi connection (closing the TCP/IP socket) and also seems to kill power to its USB ports so I can't wake it up with the KB or mouse I have temporarily connected.

In another answer I found

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = 0.1f;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

But that (or substituting 0.0f) only slightly dims the  backlight -- maybe 25%-50%

Hoping for something along the lines of TurnScreenOffButLeaveEverythingElseAlone() and TurnScreenBackOn() -- but I haven't figured out how yet...

TL;dr - Android Noob. Looking for way to power display on/off without causing collateral damage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "it also seems it drops the WiFi connection (closing the TCP/IP socket) and also seems to kill power to its USB ports so I can't wake it up with the KB or mouse I have temporarily connected" -- that is not tied strictly to the screen being on. Your Android device is going into a low-power mode. `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` happens to indicate to the OS that the user is probably doing something without much input (e.g., watching a movie) and so it should not go into low-power mode. So, focus less on the screen and more on power (e.g., use a `WakeLock` and `WifiLock`).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for that insight (and helping me find the existence of `WifiLock` -- had not come across that one in my previous searches)!

Have implemented both and it appears that when combined with adding/removing `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` I'm very close to what I wanted to accomplish -- pretty sure at this point just a bit of polish on when I acquire and release the locks will get me completely there.

Thanks again!